# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'const wchar_t *

Tags: mfc, cstring

I'm new to MFC and I don't know what to do with this error.

**ERROR**

> error C2664: 'void ATL::CStringT::Format(const
>   wchar_t *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [6]' to
>   'const wchar_t *'

heres the line:

```
m_Echo1.Format("%d %",state.dwMemoryLoad);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a Windows app is set to use 16-bit characters, not 8-bit characters. Change your quoted string to L"%d %" to specify a string of 16-bit characters.

Comment: Two comments: It's almost always better to use the T macros - so `_T("%d %%")`. And a single, standalone `%` is not a valid format specifier. I believe that newer versions of the Microsoft libraries raise a security exception at runtime when they encounter one.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 distinct errors with the line of code you posted:

1. The format string contains an illegal format specifier (trailing `%`). If you want a format string to contain a literal percent-sign it has to be escaped using `%%`.
2. You are using a string literal that does not match the required encoding, i.e. a mismatch between ANSI and UNICODE character encoding. If `m_Echo1` is of type `CString` the parameter has to be wrapped inside a `_T` or `TEXT` macro: `_T( "%d %%" )`. If `m_Echo1` is of type `CStringW` the parameter must be passed as a UNICODE string literal by prepending it with `L`: `L"%d %%"`.

*Note: The error message you posted does not match the line of code. The error message refers to `const char [6]` while the string literal in your code is of type `const char [5]`. Make sure that error messages and code match up.*